# Javascript onclick function issue

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

I'm using Jplayer on my page. The issue is that the `onclick` function is working good for player but on same time it is preventing all other `href` links on the page. How can I deal with this?

```
<script> 
$(".track, .cp-play").click(function(){
    ("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: $(this).attr("data-mp3")
    }).jPlayer("play");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console? Incidentally, you seem to be missing a `$` inside your click-handler, should be: `$('#jquery_player_1')` I imagine? Also, this should only intercept, or otherwise 'handle,' clicks on the `.track` and `.cp-play` elements, *not* the whole page.

Comment: Well yes its there , i missed here while typing

Comment: Since there's nothing wrong with the Javascript, maybe the problem is in your HTML. Please post it.

Comment: Oh thanks David :) i was doing blunder here adding .track too in there :( its Gone now :)

Comment: If the `$` isn't really missing, please fix the question.

Comment: If your links contain either `class='track'` or `class='cp-play'` then they won't work, because you `return false` on them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not returning false at the end of your click callback.

Returning false in a callback like that prevents the event from propagating up to other listeners.

It seems unlikely though that this is the solution to your problem because I'd imagine .track and .cp-play divs don't contain any links.

Comment: That's why I asked him to post his HTML, so we could see the relationship before trying to guess an answer like this.